# chartjs: automatic data sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, chart.js, stacked-chart

I need to automatically sort (in descending order) a dataset like this.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart')
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true
      },
      x: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  },
  data: {
    labels: ['A','B','C'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Year 2020',
      data: [10,20,25],
      backgroundColor: '#ff0000'
    },{
      label: 'Year 2021',
      data: [15,15,10],
      backgroundColor: '#00ff00'
    },{
      label: 'Year 2022',
      data: [30,5,25],
      backgroundColor: '#0000ff'
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id='bar-chart'></canvas>
```

Is there a chartjs plugin with capability to automatically change sorting in accordance with label currently shown or the unique possible approach is to sort data before to render them?

On other hands this is what I get:
[image]

But I would like instead...

- sequence "C","A","B" (having all labels selected)
- sequence "C","B","A" (if only "Year 2020" is selected)

Comment: You can do the sorting manually using `sort`

Comment: noted. So "manually" is the unique possible approach, isn't it?
This means also that upon the label selection, I need to implement a function to sum visible data and then to sort differently.

Comment: Seems like it, I've searched a bit but doesn't seems like chartjs provides any ways to apply custom sorting, so I'd just reorganize the data so you can easily sort them as you'd like before passing to chartjs